# NEAR Protocol Fungible Tokens logic NEP-21

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I have questions about:
[fungible Token example](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/fungible-token/src/lib.rs) and [NEP-21](https://github.com/near/NEPs/pull/21) itself.

1. It's a possible situation when `escrow allowances > 0`, but `account balance = 0`.
   Is it legal flow and why?
2. It never checks `account_id` exists or not. Why? Is it secure?
3. Anyone can call: `inc_allowance/dec_allowance`?

And for `let owner_id = env::predecessor_account_id();` will be created new account, new escrow allowance automatically (if not exist). Is that logic correct and why?

4. `get_account` always created a new account. It looks redundant.

For example:

```
fn get_account(&self, owner_id: &AccountId) -> Account {
    assert!(env::is_valid_account_id(owner_id.as_bytes()), "Owner's account ID is invalid");
    let account_hash = env::sha256(owner_id.as_bytes());
    self.accounts.get(&account_hash).unwrap_or_else(|| Account::new(account_hash))
}
```

Will create "always" new account for new `owner_id`. And it's possible then that account will never be used. So is it really practical to silently "create" an account with `get_account`?

5. `transfer_from` is never check `owner_id` as the real owner of the account. Is there logic to protect transferring only by real owners?
6. Why fungible token doesn't have a name/title?
7. Do the **NEAR Protocol** have some standard or logic for Fungible Tokens exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a possible situation when escrow allowances > 0, but account balance = 0. Is it legal flow and why?

AFAIU allowance is just a sanity upper bound that prevents abuse. Two accounts can have two allowance for the same account that together sum up to a number larger than account balance.

> It never checks account_id exists or not. Why? Is it secure?

In a sharded blockchain it is impossible to check for account existence without an asynchronous cross-contract call, since that other account might live on a different shard. Additionally, by the time we get a reply from that other shard this account can be created/deleted.

> Anyone can call: inc_allowance/dec_allowance?

It can be only called by the owner, see: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/fungible-token/src/lib.rs#L106

> And for let owner_id = env::predecessor_account_id(); will be created new account, new escrow allowance automatically (if not exist). Is that logic correct and why?

Yes. I am not sure, why this would be contradictory.

> get_account always created a new account. It looks redundant.

It might be redundant, but it also might be optimized out by the compiler in situations like this one: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/fungible-token/src/lib.rs#L213

> transfer_from is never check owner_id as the real owner of the account. Is there logic to protect transferring only by real owners?

It is implied in this check: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/fungible-token/src/lib.rs#L174-L180 If it is not the case of an escrow, then `env::predecessor_account_id()` should be equal to `owner_id`. So the receipt/transaction must have been sent from the account of the owner.

> Why fungible token doesn't have a name/title?

We are working on adding metadata to our contracts, see our Q1 OKRs here: https://airtable.com/shrw0AD36eIbfEW02

> Do the NEAR Protocol have some standard or logic for Fungible Tokens exchange?

We have partners working on implementing something similar, but I don't think we have a standard.